# RichFaces 4.2 Calendar. How can I set the InputField of Calendar by JavaScript?

Tags: java

I have to copy a Date String at client side to the Calendar input field "renewal_date_input". The following JavaSript did not work:

```
document.getElementById('AddressDetails:renewal_date_input').value = renewalDateCombo.value.toString();
```

Although with:

```
alert("written date is: " + document.getElementById('AddressDetails:renewal_date_input').value);
```

We can read out the correct date string written previously.
But the string does not appear in the input field.
Manual Input is enabled:

```
enableManualInput="true"
```

Perhaps the JavaScript Function `setInputField: function(dateStr, event)` shipped with rich faces `calendar.js` could help, but how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setValue()` function on the date component, passing a `Date` object as argument

```
 var theCalendar = document.getElementById('AddressDetails:renewal_date_input');
 theCalendar.setValue(document.getElementById('AddressDetails:renewal_date_input').getValue()); //Here I assume renewal_date_input is also a calendar component
```